# Por que a Condição ELSE valida mesmo a IF sendo True?

Tags: javascript

```
 let valor=prompt("Digite um Numero:")

if(valor<20){
  alert("Valor menor que 20")}
if(valor==20){
  alert("Valor Igual a 20") }
    else {
  alert("Valor maior que 20")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O uso do seu condicional está errado.

Pelo que entendi, uma possível solução para o seu problema seria:

```
let valor=prompt("Digite um número:")

if(valor<20){ 
    alert("Valor menor que 20")
} else if(valor==20){ 
    alert("Valor Igual a 20") 
} else {
    alert("Valor maior que 20")
}
```

Repare que temos um encadeamento do comando condicional `if`

Comment: Era isso mesmo , encadeamento ! valeu !